# v-html not working as expected when using imported raw html

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a component in Vue2 with vue-cli/3 that has a lot of raw HTML. Rather then clutter my component I thought I would abstract it out as a separate module and import it. However when rendering I get the following error:

```
Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "
    <img src="../assets/img/elizabeth_i_article.jpg" alt="Elizabeth the I">
    <p>Elizabeth I, bynames <strong>the Virgin Queen</strong> and <strong>Good Queen Bess</strong>, (born September blah blah lot more ...
```

I see in vue tools that there is a component entry under App with the html as a name and has my value of elizabethTheI : "html here....". Also the image in first line does not render. But all other HTML renders OK.

My setup is

elizabeth_I.js:

```
const elizabethTheI = `
    <img src="../assets/img/elizabeth_i_article.jpg" alt="Elizabeth the I">
    <p>Elizabeth 
    ... more html
  `
export default elizabethTheI;
```

Elizabeth_I.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Elizabeth the I</h1>

    <div v-html="elizabethTheI"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import elizabethTheI from "./assets/elizabeth_I";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      elizabethTheI: elizabethTheI
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I have read thru docs and several tutorials and I think I am using v-html directive correctly. Any insight as to why I am getting error and image not rendering would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your image won’t render because Vue will not transform asset URLs in a string. Instead of it being a string why not just use a Single File Component that just has the markup in a template? It’s far more manageable that way than editing a string that can become malformed.

Comment: You mean another SFC with just template? Interesting. I thought I could KISS by just a simple .js w/one export statement.

Comment: Also why are you using that HTML string as component name (`name: elizabethTheI`) ?

Comment: Sorry that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Because you’re exporting a string which in module language equates to an object. Vue doesn’t see it as a string. You could cast it as a string by `String(elizabethTheI)` but really the correct way is to define it as a template component and just import and use  it as a plain component. No v-html required then.

Comment: So string literals only for v-html. Thanks.